# Vertical scroll bar not working or showing up

Tags: html, css

I have created this html file where data is loaded using ajax requests but there is an awkward problem going with it. It is not showing me vertical scroll in any browser.

**html**

```
<div id="register1">
  <h2><center>Live Conversation</center></h2>
  <div id="showall">
    //data is loaded here using ajax request
  </div>
  <div id="white">
    <center>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="97" id="writebody"></textarea>
    </center>
    <br> // $msg is already set in my file
    <input type="button" name="enterbody" value="send" id="enterbody<?php echo $msg; ?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#register1 {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 100px
}

#white {
    background: white;
    height: auto
}
```

what might be the problem.

Comment: Please set up an example on a service like jsfiddle.

Comment: Where do you expect scroll bar to appear?

Comment: I am just guessing that the `showall` element becomes large, if so try: `#showall {overflow:scroll;}`

Comment: i tried  #showall {overflow:scroll;} but it didn't work. justinas appearing of scroll bar doesn't matter but the page didn't scroll at all.

Comment: I have another problem similar to this, my vertical scroll bar on model work on chrome but does not appear.

Comment: @d4rty 's comment worked for me 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a height on your results container `#showall`

```
#showall {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: As some general notes, replace `<center>` elements (which is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) with a `div` of class of `.center { text-align: center; }` (you won't need the `<br>` element, then).

Comment: well this method solved my problem to little bit. Thanks bro.

Comment: Great, thanks - if you could check this as the right answer, that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll property work with content height and width along with overflow property,

if your content height and width is less the screen height and width in that case scroll will not appear, if content got out of container height and width scroll will come

check on following like

window scroll
http://fiddly.org/4b43b

container scroll
http://fiddly.org/4b43b/2